# How to join two tables from different databases using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to make this query join two tables from different databases?. I already have configured database.php in CodeIgniter with the two databases.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '******',
    'password' => '******',
    'database' => '******',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['simak'] = array( 
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '103.124.44.13',
    'username' => '******',
    'password' => '******',
    'database' => '******',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'port'      => 21,
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

My model

```
function __construct() {
    $this->db_simak = $this->load->database('simak', true);
}

private function List() {
    $this->db->select('a.*, b.nama_diklat, c.kode_ese');
    $this->db->from('kis_diklats a');
    $this->db_simak->join('md_diklat b', 'a.id_diklat = b.id_diklat', 'left');
    $this->db_simak->join('m_unor c', 'a.kode_ese = c.kode_ese', 'left');
    
    if ($this->session->userdata('level') != 1) {
        $this->db->where('a.dihapus_oleh', NULL);
    }
```

Error notice

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'b.nama_diklat' in 'field list'
SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`nama_diklat`, `c`.`kode_ese` FROM `kis_diklats` `a` ORDER BY `diinput_tgl` DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: you cannot join different databases, those are two separate database connections

Comment: Is there any other solution for the condition? @FazlanAhamed

Comment: you need to do a separate query from both databases and do a manual check

Comment: It's not possible to join two different columns using one query. But for doing so you have to get your records from both databases, then you have to check both results, then check match the records according to your condition of joining.I hope you got my point.